# Is it good to use asynchronous API calls?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I want to know if the code below executes the next statement while waiting for the async API call? If so, then the value would be null and might cause a null exception? Am I doing this correctly?

```
var response = await pl_httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetInfo?CardNo=" + CardNo);
            
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
{ 
return response.StatusCode); 
}

InfoModel infoModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<InfoModel>();
            
if(infoModel == null){ return "Card number is invalid"; }
            
if (infoModel.ExpiryDate < DateTime.Now.Date) { return "Expired Card Number"; }
            
if (!infoModel.MemberStatus.Equals("1")) { return "Inactive Card Number"; }
```

Comment: `await` says that you wait until it finish, the thread however, might do another processing (on another context) if any.

Comment: Clarify your question. Are you asking whether the async call waits until finishes?

Comment: `await` awaits. end of story

Comment: have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way [I like to think about it](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) is that `await` pauses the method but not the thread. So for code like this:

```
var response = await pl_httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetInfo?CardNo=" + CardNo);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

The entire method is paused at the `await` statement until the download is complete. Then the method resumes executing, sets the `response` variable, and then proceeds with checking `response.IsSuccessStatusCode`.